# Call Restlet Services from Play Framework

Tags: java, web-services, playframework, restlet

There is an application implemented with Restlet that provides a service.

I have a web application written with the Play! Framework that should call the service from the above mentioned application.

I am using following code in play:

```
    HttpResponse resp = WS.url("http://blabla/bla").get();
    contact = resp.getString();
```

Is it possible to receive java objects and not only string or xml? Can I somehow 'attach' an interface of the submitted resource to the WS in my play application?

Or can I simply use the Restlet in my play application?

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just convert the XML into a Java object, using something like JAXB - [see here](http://www.mkyong.com/java/jaxb-hello-world-example/). JAXB should be powerful enough for your needs.